# Is "overflow" reserved for higher level questions and .stackexchange for lower level questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

For a year I have known of the Stack Exchange sites and find them very stimulating and useful. Last year I started using Stack Overflow and this year started using `math.stackexchange.com`.

Sometimes, however, when I google a math subject I end up on `mathoverflow.net`, which is also part of SE but reserved for higher level math questions. Now I am left wondering: Did I use Stack Overflow wrongly as I posted low-level questions? Or is the math section the only section where the distinction between `*.stackexchange.com` and `*overflow.com` means a distinction in level?

Comment: Not sure what you ask. Each site in the Stack Exchange network stands on its own and is independent. There might be similar topics on some, but still, there's no such distinction as you mention.

Comment: FWIW, mathoverflow.net does not seem to be part of the SE network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note: https://mathoverflow.net/ has now upgraded to the SE 2.0 platform**

<del>MathOverflow is not yet a part of the Stack Exchange network, though there are plans to [migrate them to SE 2.0](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1082/1/migrate-to-se-20/). (They are currently running the Stack Exchange 1.0 platform if I'm not mistaken)</del> As such, there is no distinction in level indicated by the Overflow or Exchange name.

Each site within the network sets its own scope for acceptable questions. There is no reason why a Stack Exchange site could not limit itself to "high level" or academic level questions.

As for your "low level" questions on Stack Overflow, if they were good questions and were not closed/deleted, they were probably acceptable for the site.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you thought the term overflow meant the site was here to catch the excess from other Stack Exchange sites. Similar to that of an "overflow channel" that can be dug near a river to deal with the runoff and negate the effects of flooding.

StackOverflow is actually named from an error which can occur in software development. [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)
In a nutshell the "Stack" is essentially available memory, so when you try and assign more than it can contain it "Overflows" and causes an error.

So it's basically a nerdy reference to the central topic of this particular site.

Comment: Yes i did not understand that at first, a friend explained it to me much the same way you did. This however was not the reason of my question. The reason I asked this question was because there seemed to be two mathematics stackexchanges, one for lower and one for higher complexity.